# How to figure out the found library type by cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am linking my pybind11 based project to python library, and I have lines below in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Development)
if (Python_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(${TARGET} PUBLIC ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

It works but has a problem when I try to make it cross platform, e.g, for Windows, the found PYTHON_LIBRARIES is the python3x.lib, but on Linux(Ubuntu 18.04) it becomes libpython3xm.so.

What bothers me is that the PYTHON_LIBRARIES is static under windows but shared under Linux, and thus for windows I have to add line below to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PUBLIC ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

However if I add this line for Linux, I will often get errors of multiple definition error if I link my TARGET to some library that is also used by libpython3xm.so but with a different version.

I tried to use `set(Python_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)`, but seems does not change the type of the found PYTHON_LIBRARIES.

so my question is if there a way to check the property of the PYTHON_LIBRARIES and only add the `target_link_libraries` when it is static, or if there is a way to work around?

**UPDATE**
I put the following in my CMakeLists.txt file and the output still gives .so shared lib

```
set(Python_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Development)
message(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

> [cmake] -- Found Python: /usr/include/python3.7m (found version
> "3.7.5") found components: Development Development.Module
> Development.Embed  [cmake] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so

Comment: Setting variable `Python_USE_STATIC_LIBS` should work. Make sure that you set it **before** `find_package` call and, if previously you configure your project without the variable, clear CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory) before new attempt.

Comment: @Tsyvarev See my update, it seems still not working as expected even cleaned and reconfigured. did i miss anything?